Weekly Topic Challenge: Let's ask about Zcash‽
Zcash is about to be released today. It's a peer-to-peer cryptocurrency implementing the Zerocash scheme. It promises complete transactional confidentiality.
A bold claim, will it stand up to scrutiny? ;)
Currently, we have 5 questions, and surely the imminent launch will generate more this week.
Please use zcash to tag your questions, and consider asking any questions about development, launch, implementation, new vocabulary, security, mining, privacy properties, or whatever else you want to know about it.
This weekly topic challenge runs until 2016-11-03. Happy posting!

Challenge accepted!

Yay, interrobang. – I like it!

I was late to participate but just asked by 1st question

This week, three questions were asked about Zcash with a total of three answers:

Zcash proposal to use checkpoints to verify monetary supply – 2quick 4u [+2]
Is equihash/scrypt suitable for pooled mining? – fiction [+4]
How to generate a zcash vanity address? –   5chdn [+3]

Thanks for posting!
